# How to place image outside collapsible section in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need some help with bootstrap 4 and css. I have shared the code below

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>

  </div>
</nav>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please see it live in https://codepen.io/kofhearts/pen/YjQZNM

In the link is a bootstrap 4 example with navbar. There is a cart icon to the right of search bar. What i want to achieve is at the expanded state the cart should be present as it is now i.e right of search section but when the section collapses in mobile views, the cart should not be in collapsible section but it should be to the left of the toggle button. I have attached an image of expected result

[image]

How can I achieve this using css or any other method?

**UPDATE:**

In the original code the cart is wrapped with anchor like follows. So the solution should work when the cart is wrapped with anchor tag

```
<a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart ml-auto moving-cart" style="font-size: 24px; margin-right: 15px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember when using bootstrap, to always design from mobile first. So I have set your cart to float to the left of your navbar toggler initially on mobile. Then once the width reaches the `lg` breakpoint, I change the positioning of the cart to be absolute and set it to the far right of the navbar, while givng the navbar some room with `pr-lg-5`

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .moving-cart {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.moving-cart {
  font-size: 24px !important;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light pr-lg-5">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <a href="#" class="ml-auto"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart moving-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
    
    
    
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi dan, when i wrap the cart with anchor tag like <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart ml-auto moving-cart" style="font-size: 24px; margin-right: 15px;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>. it puts a weird space between the toggler and the cart. can you please suggest a fix to this? thanks for help. ill accept after this fix.

Comment: @kofhearts No problem, just move the `ml-auto` to the `<a>` instead!:) I also added some more css to help with the additional styles that the `<a>` tag gets with bootstrap. Here is an updated pen: https://codepen.io/djpeach/pen/OwjRJY

Answer (score 0):

It looks bit hacky, but see if it works for you.

```css
.collapsed-right {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-shopping-cart {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 991px) {
  .d-small {
    display: inherit
  }
}

@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .d-large {
    display: inherit
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapsed-right">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart d-small" style="font-size: 24px; margin-right: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart d-large" style="font-size: 24px; margin-left: 5px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</nav>
```

Comment: It is generally bad practice to add `(max-width)` media queries when using bootstrap, always try to design from mobile size to desktop size and use `(min-width)` queries.